# req.params.id returning multiple values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a form that upon submission, redirects to "/room/roomnum", in my chat app. On redirect, chat.html is displayed. But inside app.get, I have room/:id, and 'id' should have the value of the room number entered in the form.

```
   app.post("/user", urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
        res.redirect("/room/" + req.body.roomnum);
    });
    app.get("/room/:id", function(req,res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/chat.html");
        console.log(req.params.id);
    });
```

However, I am  getting multiple values in the console -

CONSOLE OUTPUT -

> roomnum
>   style.css
>   script.js

Shouldn't I be getting only the room number when I console.log(req.params.id) ?

**UPDATE - Main part of the app**

```
//routing
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login", {rooms: rooms});
});
app.post("/user", urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
    res.redirect("/room/" + req.body.roomnum);
});
app.get("/room/:id", function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/chat.html");
    //console.log(req.params.id);
});
app.use(express.static("static_files"));

//handling socket connection
io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    //console.log(socket.handshake.address + " joined ");
});
```

Comment: You may be getting these multiple console outputs because of multiple console statements somewhere else in the code.

Comment: no, i checked... there is only one console statement, no loop.

Comment: if you remove or comment out this console statement, then you do not get any of these outputs in console?

Comment: No, i dont get any output.

Comment: What's the complete log statement for `style.css` and `script.js`? Is it something like this? `XHR finished loading: GET "http://example.com/style.css"`. ? If you reload this Stackoverflow with the Console open, you will see the same thing.

Comment: You may also try to realize if it was an XHR request by debugging at server the headers of the request, by using:
    console.log(req.params.id, req.headers);

Comment: One more recommendation, use path.join to get a file path, don't use / nor \\. For example:

 const path = require('path');
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "chat.html"));

If you are going to return on every request to /root/:id the same file and it's not so big you may also cache the file in memory and return it from memory. You may lost some features sendFile brings (E-tag, Max-Age) but you may gain speed when returning to different clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues here:

- in `chat.html`, you're using relative paths (without a leading `/`) to load `style.css` and `script.js`;
- you declare the static middleware too late.

Because of these issues, a request for `style.css` from inside `chat.html` is "translated" to `/room/style.css`, which matches the `/room/:id` route. It also never hits the static middleware because of that (when a route matches and processes a request, any subsequent route handlers won't get called).

So:

- use absolute paths for resources: `/style.css` (or `/css/style.css` or whatever, depending on how you structured the `static_files` directory)
- move the static middleware to *before* your routes:

  ```
  app.use(express.static("static_files"));
  //routing
  app.get("/", function(req, res) { ... }).
  ```